# Adding a redirect to CreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views, django-quiz

I want to redirect the user to the `AddQuestionsView` after the user creates a quiz(after adding title).

My CreateQuiz

```
class CreateQuizzView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateQuizSerializer
```

My serializers.py file

```
class CreateQuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Quizzer
        fields = ['title']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        new_quiz = Quizzer.objects.create(
            user=user,
            **validated_data
        )
        return new_quiz
```

Can i add redirect by adding any Mixin or change need to change the GenericView.

Comment: An `APIView` is normally *not* used by a browser, hence a redirect makes not much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `APIView` is normally *not* used by a browser, or at least not directly, hence a redirect makes not much sense. The idea is that some program makes HTTP requests, and thus retrieves a response. Most API handlers will not by default follow a redirect anyway.

You can however make a redirect, by overriding the `post` method:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class CreateQuizzView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateQuizSerializer

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().post(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect('name-of-the-view')
```